# Item description not shown in Paypal Transaction details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

Hi I'm Integrating Paypal express checkout using Activemerchant.

I'm able to make successful transaction but I'm not seeing My Item's description in transaction details page.It display all the other option correctly but the Options column is empty.

[image]

However I'm seeing Items details in the checkout page.

[image]

Here is my code.I probably doing something wrong.

```
def express_checkout

    listing = Listing.find(session[:listing_id].to_f)

    response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(session[:amount].to_f,
                                              ip: request.remote_ip,
                                              return_url: "http://esignature.lvh.me:3000/en/transactions/status",
                                              cancel_return_url: "http://esignature.lvh.me:3000/",
                                              currency: "USD",
                                              allow_guest_checkout: true,
                                              items: [{name: listing.title, description: listing.description, quantity: session[:number_of_days], amount: listing.price_cents},
                                                      {name: "Service Charge" ,description: "Service Charge", amount: session[:service_charge]}
                                              ]
    )


    redirect_to EXPRESS_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token)

  end

  def status
    if (params[:token].present? && params[:PayerID].present?)
      token = params[:token]
      @response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.details_for(token).params
      listing = Listing.find(session[:listing_id].to_f)

      express_purchase_options = {
          :ip => request.remote_ip,
          :token => params[:token],
          :payer_id => params[:PayerID],
          items: [{ name: listing.title, description: listing.description, quantity: session[:number_of_days], amount: listing.price_cents},
                  { name: "Service Charge", description: "Service Charge", amount: session[:service_charge ]}
          ]
      }

      response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.purchase(session[:amount].to_f, express_purchase_options)


      if response.message == "Success"
        listing = Listing.find(session[:listing_id].to_f)
        BookingInfo.create!(listing_id: listing.id, start_on: session[:start_date].to_date, end_on: session[:end_date].to_date)
        render 'status'
      else
        render 'status_error'
      end
      reset_session_params
    else
      reset_session_params
      redirect_to homepage_without_locale_path
    end

  end
```

here I'm setting Item details in both setup_purchase as well as in purchase.Any suggestion will be appreciated.Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, Express Checkout doesn't make use of the options column like PayPal Standard does.  You'll need to include any options like that in the item name for it to show up in the transaction details.

Comment: @AndrewAngell Thanks a lot.I did it in the same way as you suggested.
Thanks a lot once again.You made my day.